# Codeigniter and FancyBox to display image gallery

Tags: fancybox, codeigniter-3

I am using FancyBox to display image gallery. I want, When page open all images shows as thumb after click any image show this image full screen, slide show etc.

my CI view code as below

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <?php 
        foreach ($records as $rec){

           echo "<a href=".base_url()."upload/images/".$rec["file_name"]." data-fancybox="group">";

          echo  "<img src=".base_url()."upload/images/thumb/".$rec["file_name"].">";

          echo "</a>";

       } ?>
```

CI Module Code below:

```
public function get_data_gallery($table){

 $query =  $this->db->get($table);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

CI controller code as below:

```
public function gallery(){
            $data['records'] = $this->ciweb_model->get_data_gallery('images');


            $this->load->view('common/header');
            $this->load->view('common/menu');
            $this->load->view('gallery',$data);
            $this->load->view('common/footer');
        }
```

And my Error is below:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Parsing Error
Message: syntax error, unexpected 'group' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'
Filename: views/gallery.php
Line Number: 32
Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is here:

```
.. data-fancybox="group">";
```

you have mixed `"`'s, it should be

```
.. data-fancybox='group'>";
```